# OpenGL fragment shader - From window coordinates to uv

Tags: opengl, glsl

As part of an assignment, I am writing a fragment shader in which I am accessing a texture which comes from a fragment buffer. As such, I can not get the uv coordinates from the vertex shader, which means I need to compute them. I have been having problems with this version:

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
in vec2 uv;

in vec4 gl_FragCoord ;

uniform sampler2D tex; //texture of the floor
uniform sampler2D tex_mirror; //texture of the cube (used to get reflection)

void main() {

    /// TODO: query window_width/height using the textureSize(..) function on tex_mirror
    /// TODO: use gl_FragCoord to build a new [_u,_v] coordinate to query the framebuffer
    /// NOTE: make sure you normalize gl_FragCoord by window_width/height
    /// NOTE: you will have to flip the "v" coordinate as framebuffer is upside/down
    /// TODO: mix the texture(tex,uv).rgb with the value you fetch by texture(tex_mirror,vec2(_u,_v)).rgb

    int window_width = textureSize(tex_mirror, 0).x;
    int window_height = textureSize(tex_mirror, 0).y;

    float _u = gl_FragCoord.x;
    float _v = -gl_FragCoord.y;

    vec3 color_from_texture = texture(tex,uv).rgb;
    vec3 color_from_mirror = texture(tex_mirror, vec2(_u, _v)).rgb;

    color = mix(color_from_texture, color_from_mirror, vec3(.15));
}
```

The goal is to eventually get a reflective surface like this (don't mind the cube on top, only the floor and the reflection of that cube are relevant in the above fragment shader):
[image: reflective surface]

My problem is: The way I am computing the _u _v coordinates is most probably flawed, because when launching the program, I only get the floor, without the reflection.
I tried to render the reflection with the floor's uv coordinates just to see if something was displayed, and I got this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "comes from a fragment buffer"? And why would the source of the texture's data prevent you from having a texture coordinates?

Comment: Are you sure the cube is being rendered? Are there shader compiler errors? It looks to me like the cube just isn't there, period (in the first example, it is high enough it would be visible even if it were behind the floor; in he second, it's not there). Also, what is that shader actually being applied to? The floor? A plane over the entire screen?

Comment: You know that part of the assignment that says _"make sure to normalize ..."_, you need to do that. `gl_FragCoord` is in window-space, the texture lookup functions expect normalized [0,1] coordinates.